# Express rational number as the sum of 4 squares

Tags: number-theory

I need to prove that any rational number a/b can be expressed as the sum of 4 squares of rational numbers

I have tried something similar to the proof for integers, but can't get it to work.
I have tried an algebraic proof, but I keep running into the issie of potential irrational denominators

Comment: So I assume you mean the sum of 4 squares of rational numbers?

Comment: yes, thank you.

Comment: I don't understand, you can take $\frac{c}{d}$ ,$\frac{e}{f}$ , $\frac{g}{h}$  
 and $\frac{i}{j}$ square them and sum

Comment: @Enigsis It is the issue of showing, say, $1/7$ is equal to such a sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are taking $\frac{a}{b}$ with integers $a,b > 0.$ Thus $ab$ is a positive integer.

Let
$$ w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = ab  $$

Then
$$ \left( \frac{w}{b} \right)^2 +  \left( \frac{x}{b} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{y}{b} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{z}{b} \right)^2 = \frac{a}{b}$$